# How to get the current value of a mapped element?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a section for my chat application, that allows the user to go back to chatrooms they've previously visited, without having to go back to the home page, and reenter the chatroom name over again.

I've mapped and rendered a array of objects of data from firebase on the page. That shows the name of all the chat rooms the current user has visit.

I'm having trouble trying to get the value of the mapped element when I click on it, so I send that value to a useState named "setRoom" that to go chat rooms based on the name of the chat room. I tried using a useRef hook to try and get the current value of the clicked element, but it just returns undefined.

How could I get the individual values of a mapped element?

Here is my code. I added comments to make it easy to understand the code a bit clearer. The useEffect isn't that important I just added in for better context. the main areas I'm having trouble in are the "getChatroom" function, and the mapped element I'm trying to get the chat room name from.

```
  //useStates and useRef

  const [chatRoomData, setChatRoomData] = useState([]);
  const currentChatroom = useRef(null);
  
  //the function that suppose to get the current value of the clicked mapped element.
  const getChatroom = () =>{
    console.log(currentChatroom.current.value);
    //this is a proped useState i'm trying to set the name of the clicked chat room name to. 
    setRoom(currentChatroom.current.value);
  }

  //this useffect gets the data from firebase, based on if the user has visted them.
  useEffect(() =>{
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, currentUser => {
      const chatRoomCollectionRef = collection(dataBase, 'ChatRooms');

      const unSubscribe = onSnapshot(chatRoomCollectionRef, (snapshot) => {
        const chatRooms = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const messagesSubcollectionRef = collection(doc.ref, 'messages');
          const queryMessages = query(messagesSubcollectionRef, where("uid", "==", currentUser.uid));

          onSnapshot(queryMessages, (messagesSnapshot) => {
            messagesSnapshot.forEach((messagesDoc) =>{
              chatRooms.push({ chatRoom: messagesDoc.data().room, text: messagesDoc.data().text, timeStamp: messagesDoc.data().createdAt, id: messagesDoc.id });
            })
            setChatRoomData(chatRooms);
          })
        });
      })
      return () => unSubscribe();
    })
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
        <div className="chats-container">
          <header className='chats-header-container'> 
            <h1 className="chats-header">Your Previous Chat Rooms</h1>
            <h2 className='chats-subheader'>Hop right back in!</h2>
          </header>
          {/* the mapped data from firebase rendered on the page */}
          {chatRoomData.map((data) =>(
            <div className='users-chatRooms-container' key={data.id}>
              <div className='users-chatRooms-card'>
                {/* the mapped from the firebase array I'm trying to get the chatroom name from */}
                <button className='users-chatRoom-names-btn'><h2 className='users-chatRoom-names' ref={currentChatroom} onClick={getChatroom}>{data.chatRoom}</h2></button>
                <p className='users-chatRoom-latest-text'>{data.text}</p>
                {data.timeStamp === null ?(
                  <p>no time</p>
                ):(
                  <p className='message-timestamp'>-{data.timeStamp.toDate().toDateString()}</p>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Could anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: The "current value" of a mapped element is literally the currently mapped array element. In your code, it's the `data` in the `chatRoomData.map` callback. You access whatever `data.X` property you need for whatever purpose, i.e. `data.roomName`. Do you have some issue beyond just accessing your rooms data? Using a single React ref for all the mapped elements won't work as the ref will always be set to the last element. I don't think you need a ref though, just pass whatever current room data to the callback handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using a single `ref` for all the mapped elements, which is why you're having trouble getting the individual values. Instead of using a single `ref`, you can pass the chat room name directly to the `getChatroom` function as an argument. Here's an updated version of your code:

```js
// ...

const getChatroom = (chatRoomName) => {
  console.log(chatRoomName);
  setRoom(chatRoomName);
}

// ...

{chatRoomData.map((data) => (
  <div className='users-chatRooms-container' key={data.id}>
    <div className='users-chatRooms-card'>
      {/* Pass the chat room name to the function */}
      <button className='users-chatRoom-names-btn' onClick={() => getChatroom(data.chatRoom)}>
        <h2 className='users-chatRoom-names'>{data.chatRoom}</h2>
      </button>
      <p className='users-chatRoom-latest-text'>{data.text}</p>
      {data.timeStamp === null ? (
        <p>no time</p>
      ) : (
        <p className='message-timestamp'>-{data.timeStamp.toDate().toDateString()}</p>
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
))}

// ...
```

In this modified code, I've removed the `ref` from `h2` and directly passed the `data.chatRoom` to the `getChatroom` function through an anonymous arrow function in the `onClick` handler. This way, each button will pass its corresponding chat room name to the function, and you can set it in your `useState` as intended.